# Progress bar in a linux terminal

Tags: c++, shell, pipe

I recently implemented a progress bar class in C++. I wrote something like

```
cout << "\r" << percentage_done << "%" << flush;
```

Now I am running some programs piping the output to less.
The problem is that less shows me a lot of lines of the type

^M1%^M2%...

So the "\r" is not interpreted correctly. Is it possible to pipe this in such a way
that less will only show the final 100% line or do I have to add a switch to my program
to disable the progression bars entirely?

I have the same problem when I pipe the output directly to a file, so the output files
occupy a lot of disk space unnecessarily.

Comment: It's idiomatic to have an option to switch off fancy text-based GUIs. Also, you'd be better off using libncurses for unified terminal access.

Comment: Everything works as designed. You should only show progress-bar if a terminal is connected to standard output.

Comment: `"\r"` on most systems maps to `^M` - carriage return, or return to beginning of line without advancing to the next line (different than `"\n"`, newline, which means either move to beginning of next line or move down one line without changing columns); so you are getting what you are asking for. As mentioned by others, you probably need to use different formatting if `cout` isn't a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that it was quite right what Jan Hudec said. I wrote myself a small function

```
#include <unistd.h>

bool stdout_has_terminal()
{
  return NULL != ttyname(STDOUT_FILENO);
}
```

Depending on the return value I either print the progression bar or not. Now everything works quite nicely :)

Answer (score 6):

[This approach](http://ideone.com/b6bVOJ) works OK piped with less without additional options. And it works in general with any kind of output redirection.

And you don't have to check is_terminal as suggested for other approaches:

```
#include <boost/progress.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    const unsigned long expected_count=20;
    boost::progress_display show_progress( expected_count );
    for(int i=0;i!=expected_count;++i)
    {
        volatile std::vector<int> v(1024*1024*128);
        ++show_progress;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
***************************************************
```

Ruler is printed during progress_display contstructor.

And then progress bar is gradually filled with ***** on ++show_progress;

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-r` option to `less` to have it interpret the control sequences. Compare:

```
echo -e '1\r2\r3\r4\r100' | less
echo -e '1\r2\r3\r4\r100' | less -r
```